# Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am working on wsl2:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on Windows 10 x86_64
Kernel: 4.19.104-microsoft-standard
Uptime: 2 mins
Packages: 1329 (dpkg)
Shell: zsh 5.8
Terminal: emacs
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 4500U with Radeon Graphics (6) @ 2.370GHz
Memory: 201MiB / 12277MiB
```

When try to upgrade all apps, it report errors:

```
➜  gaowei sudo apt upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 emacs-bin-common : Depends: emacs-common (= 1:26.3+1-1ubuntu2) but it is not insta
lled
 emacs-el : Depends: emacs-common (= 1:26.3+1-1ubuntu2) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify
a solution).
```

Unfortunately, it does not help to run `--fix-broken` but report errors:

```
Preparing to unpack .../emacs-common_1%3a26.3+1-1ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking emacs-common (1:26.3+1-1ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-common_1%3a26.3+1-1ubun
tu2_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/emacs-module.h', which is also in package emacs26
-common 26.3~1.git96dd019-kk1+20.04
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-common_1%3a26.3+1-1ubuntu2_all.deb
```

It report the errors repeatedly, whatever packages I tried to install.

How could I solve the problem if not reinstall ubuntu on wsl?

The emacs26 could not been removed:

```
➜  gaowei sudo apt remove --purge emacs26
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 emacs-bin-common : Depends: emacs-common (= 1:26.3+1-1ubuntu2) but it is not going
 to be installed
 emacs-el : Depends: emacs-common (= 1:26.3+1-1ubuntu2) but it is not going to be i
nstalled
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify
a solution).
```

Comment: A quick look shows it's found in 'universe', do you have universe enabled?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: Remove package emacs26

Comment: @nobody ty. I updated the question, emacs26 cannot be removed.

Comment: Not with apt please it is blocked. `sudo dpkg -P emacs26`